# Setting Menu as Sliding Menu causing crash when inflating

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm currently trying to implement the sliding menu open source library into a project I'm working on, and after lots of battling with configurations and whatnot it's finally imported successfully.

I am trying to implement Sliding Menu in a class ProfileActivity which extends SingleFragmentActivity which extends the included FragmentActivity class.

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
protected abstract int getContentViewlayout();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentViewlayout());
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

}

However, this block of code in my ProfileActivity class is causing the app to crash when I'm testing it:

```
slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
```

Specifically, the last line

`slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);`

results in this logcat output:

```
03-08 21:29:19.015  30272-30272/au.com.jobinhood.android.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: au.com.jobinhood.android.app, PID: 30272
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{au.com.jobinhood.android.app/au.com.jobinhood.android.app.activity.ProfileActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
        at au.com.jobinhood.android.app.activity.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

The menu was implemented following the tutorial from this site: http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html.

If I take out the offending line, the menu slides out but it is just white space, whereas if I include it, upon switching to the fragment (from a menu item that launches this Fragment, B, from another Fragment, A) it will crash without me needing to try and swipe the menu out first.

The actual setMenu method that is resulting in the crash resides in the slidingMenu library which I have not touched after importing:

```
setMenu(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(res, null));
```

Please note that the logcat is incomplete - I couldn't include one long logcat even splitting it into multiple blocks with a line in between as everything after what I already have there was included as plain text despite choosing the formatting option. The full logcat can be found at this location:

http://pastebin.com/2LaBGsQ7.

Any help on identifying the root cause of the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember you Activity should extend SlidingFragmentActivity but I could be wrong. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `logcat` line 38:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
```

at ( logcat line 50 )

`au.com.jobinhood.android.app.activity.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:52)`

maybe this is your problem...

P.S.: Just a heads up:
`FragmentActivity` uses the `support.v4.app` library to load, so you have to use `getSupportFramentManager()` to load and find fragments.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue and following the same tutorial I did - there was a mistake in the instructions (or at least by attaching it to my existing code) that caused the crash.

On the second page (http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-22-690.html), it tells you to edit res/layout/slidingmenu.xml to a fragment, but this breaks the sliding menu. Leaving it as per the instructions on page 1 allows it to function.